# Vue js Property or Method "theSport" not defined on the instance

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am working on a simple form in VueJs and I do not fully understand why my code is showing in error.

"[Vue warn]: Property or method "theSport" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render"

I have searched around on google and codepen (even modeling my form after those that are working) and I still get the same issue. Could anyone point me in the direction of where I am going wrong?

```
<template>
    <form>
        <select name="" id="sportPlayed" v-model="selected">
            <option v-bind:value="theSport.sport" v-bind:for="theSport in sportPlayed">{{ theSport.sport }}</option>
        </select>
        <br>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "FullName",
    data:() => {
        return {
            selected: "Football",
            sportPlayed: [
                {sport: "Football"},
                {sport: "Basketball"},
                {sport: "Baseball"},
                {sport: "Soocer"}
            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Change `v-bind:for` to `v-for`.

Comment: @skirtle after making the change i have noticed that it is in the background working and looks like this is actually a es-lint error instead, going to do more research on this but thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use v-for="theSport in sportPlayed" instead of v-bind:for="theSport in sportPlayed" to loop through the sportPlayed array.

Check the List Rendering documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html